# google maps : how to draw markers as rounded-border images?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using this jquery lib: 
http://tilotiti.github.io/jQuery-Google-Map/

The result I obtain is:

[image]

I would like this picture to be border-rounded (circle)

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score -1):

If the image is `<img src=''>` tag then try to apply one of the css

HTML

```
<img class="round_img" src="your image">
```

CSS

```
.round_img {
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width:200px;
}
```

OR

```
.round_img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: this is for HTML. Did you ever try google maps ? This is canvas.